# Using CTime & asctime to assign time to a string or vector string

Tags: c++, string, ctime

I would like to use asctime to assign the time to a string.

```
time_t rawtime;
time ( &rawtime );
vector<string> TTime;
TTime.resize(10);
TTime = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
```

I understand asctime is returning a pointer to a string. Would i have to create my own string and assign it the return value of asctime, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a string directly from a `char *`:

```
string str = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
```

This doesn't make sense:

```
TTime = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
```

You can't assign a single string to a vector of strings. What you *can* do is:

```
TTime[0] = asctime(localtime ( &rawtime ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is a simple string,

```
std::string TTime(asctime(localtime(&rawtime)));
```

Comment: This did work. I'm not sure why but I assumed each string could only hold one word & a space ended the string.

Answer (score 0):

The function asctime() return char*
and the std::string can construct from char*

std::string time(asctime(localtime(&rawtime)));

or

std::string time;
time = asctime(asctimer(localtimer(&rawtime)));